# Closing IActiveScript engine throws E_UNEXPECTED exception

Tags: c#, scripting

Working with C# in .NET, I am trying to call [`IActiveScript.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fds63c9(VS.85).aspx) on my instance of the Windows Scripting host.

Since I am currently hunting memory leaks, I discovered that I did not call this `Close` method and tried to add the missing code. So I added a call to the `Close`method.

Unfortunately, when calling the `Close` method, a COM exception is thrown with E_UNEXPECTED as the error code.

Querying the script state of the engine before closing it, it returns [`SCRIPTSTATE_CONNECTED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7z7cxxa(VS.85).aspx).

**Question:**

How can I gracefully call `IActiveScript.Close` without getting an exception thrown?

Comment: Are you sure the object hasn't already been closed? From the documentation I get the idea that Close has already been called on it.

Comment: Thanks, Pieter. Probably I did something wrong on the order of the functions I called. The example in my answer below works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To (partially) answer my own question:

I finally managed to build a [stand-alone test application](http://blog.magerquark.de/2010-10/using-active-scripting-from-within-c-without-leaking-memory/) where I successfully can call the `IActiveScript.Close` method and also have no memory leaks.